# KnockoutJS Object doesn't support 'toFixed'

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using KnockoutJS and am running into an issue that I have no idea how to go about finding a solution to:

I have a table containing records:

```
<script type="text/html" id="myItemsTemplate">
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: MyNumber().toFixed(2)"></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.editItem">Edit</button></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.enterHours">Enter Hours</button></td>
</tr>
```

Initially "MyNumber().toFixed(2)" was just "MyNumber", but I was running into an issue where "MyNumber" wouldn't show decimal places or would show more than 2 decimal places depending on the value (if the value was "7.00" it would show just "7" and if it was "7.345345" it would show the full "7.345345").  So I changed it to "MyNumber().toFixed(2)".

That seemed to fixe the display, however now it seems that has broken the update portion:

```
<script type="text/html" id="myEditTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value: MyNumber" class="table-edit" /></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.acceptItemEdit">Save</button></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" data-bind="click: $root.cancelItemEdit">Cancel</button></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Here, when I attempt to save the record it will save it, but will also return the error:

Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'toFixed';
Bindings value: text: MyNumber().toFixed(2)

I've tried changing the edit template so it uses: 
ko.utils.unwrapObservable(MyNumber()).toFixed(2)
or
MyNumber().toFixed(2) to match the item template.  That results in no Javascript error, but also does not update the value.

I've seen posts saying this is because "MyNumber" isn't an observable so I tried unwrapObservable().  Other than that I am not sure where I should be looking to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Your problem sounds familiar, but the question doesn't allow us to reproduce it. Please include more (yet minimal) code to repro it, preferably add a Stack Snippet (on the editor toolbar).

Comment: Can you verify that for all values of `MyNumber` that it is actually a number (and not null, a string, an object, an array, etc.)?

Comment: Try to avoid performing operations in view . For better maintainability use computed or binding handlers .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your problem description I reproduced a test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/w2nae2dq/.
@icktoofay is right for one part: it is better to use a computed observable (but it is not required *per se*). If you need to show the 2 decimal value to edit you will need a writable computed observable. If however, you only want to display the 2 decimal number and make the `MyNumber` value editable, check the fiddle for a demo.

In any case, the problem with your code was one of **type conversion**. Indeed, when you first set the value of `MyNumber` it is a number. However, when a user enters a new value in the  `<input>` (and thus updates `MyNumber`), this value is set as a **string** value, which makes it impossible for the `text:` binding to execute the `toFixed` method on. So your computed observable would look like this:

```
self.MyNumberRounded = ko.computed(function() {
    return parseFloat(self.MyNumber()).toFixed(2); // note parseFloat
}, self);
```

And that's why `Object doesn't support property` :)

Comment: It looks like this is the cause and solution.  I think it also explains why the error didn't pop up if I didn't not change the numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t used KnockoutJS, but from their documentation, it looks like you need to create a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

```
this.formattedMyNumber = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.MyNumber().toFixed(2);
}, this);
```

And then bind to that:

```
<td data-bind="text: formattedMyNumber"></td>
```

If you want to use the formatted version in the edit view as well, you may need to use [writable computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html).

Comment: This made sense to me, but it seems like the issue is deeper than that.  Even if I use a computer observable it gives the same error.  I think Tyblitz's example shows why.